# Align two inline-block div with content

Tags: html, css

I have two inline-block divs, each 50% width of its parent, and they are correctly shown next to each other. But, when I add a link to one of those divs, there's a gap on top of the second div

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="resizable resizable1"> 
    <a href="#" class="link1">link1</a>
    <a href="#" class="link2">link2</a>
  </div><!-- 
  --><div class="resizable resizable2">second</div>
</div>

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}
.resizable {
  width: 50%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: coral;
  display: inline-block;
}
.resizable2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.resizable a {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/KyEr3/455/

How can align the two divs?

Comment: Looks fine to me, can you explain what you're seeing (maybe a screenshot will help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `display: inline-block` elements by default are set to `baseline`, instead set `vertical-align: top`

```
.resizable {
        width: 50%;
        height: 120px;
        background-color: coral;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyEr3/457/)

Comment: @Carlo yes it's a `vertical-align` issue, ill update the language in my post

Answer (score 0):

You can also float them both left, they will align next to each other in the wrapper.

```
 .wrap {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
}
.resizable {
    width: 50%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: coral;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.resizable2 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    float:left;
}
.resizable a {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```